# Add ability to search for a category name in ajax search field wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have a Wordpress ajax search field that the user can search for products. I want to be able to search by product category also. "Whats new", "limited edition", etc. How would I query and display the category name?

Also I need the user to be able to search by location name and when clicked direct to a location page. So if they search "Walmart" or "Target" the link would always go to the location page. The location would not be a taxonomy so I'm guessing this would have to be hardecoded with all the locations names which is fine. How would I hardcode this into a query?

```
<?php
/*
** Custom search ajax
*/
add_action('wp_ajax_custom-search', 'search_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom-search', 'search_ajax');
function search_ajax() {

 if($_GET['s'] === '') {
wp_send_json(array(
    'results' => [],

));
}
else {
$query = new WP_Query( array('s' => $_GET['s'], 'post_type' =>    array('product', 'tutorial') ) );

$query2 = new WP_Query( array('tag' => sanitize_title_with_dashes($_GET['s'])     . ',' . sanitize_title_with_dashes(preg_replace('/s$/i', '', $_GET['s'])) . ',' . sanitize_title_with_dashes(preg_replace('/es$/i', '', $_GET['s'])) , 'post_type' => array('product', 'tutorial') ) );






    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->posts = array_merge( $query->posts, $query2->posts );
    $wp_query->post_count = $query->post_count + $query2->post_count;



wp_send_json(array(
    'results' => array_map(function($p) { return array( 'title'=>get_the_title($p),'uri'=>get_permalink($p),'category'=>get_the_category($p->ID, 'search_category'),'postType'=>get_post_type($p),'thumb'=>get_the_post_thumbnail($p->ID,'medium')); }, $wp_query->posts)
));
   }  


 }



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you probably query when printing the page for the categories / locations, i would have just printed the list into a JS array, and then work with a autocomplete plugin. Ex: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
But in some cases i would prefer ajax live search, not this case.